# Integration for Hadoop using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Is there any library that I can use to integrate `Hive/Impala/Spark` scripts using `Robot Framework`?

I tried using `pyodbc`, but it forces to connect to SQL Server:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem

Suite Setup         Connect To Database       pyodbc  ${DBName}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPass}   ${DBHost}   ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown      Disconnect From Database

*** Variables ***
${DBName}   xxxx
${DBUser}   xxxx
${DBPass}   xxxx
${DBHost}   xxxx
${DBPort}   10000

*** Test Cases ***
Create person table
    ${output}=  Execute SQL String  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
    log to console  ${output}
    should be equal as strings  ${output}   None
```

The output:

```
Parent suite setup failed:
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53
)')
```

Anyone have an example how I can connect `Robot Framework` to `Hive/Impala`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DatabaseLibrary is based on DB API 2.0 which supports these database systems: [Generic Database Interfaces and APIs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces). So you won't be able to use this library in your case.

I think you best option would be to use a Python module and write your own library that you import into Robot. I don't really know these technologies (hive etc.) much, but it seems you can use e.g. [PyHive](https://pypi.org/project/PyHive/), you can find more on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370431/how-to-access-hive-via-python)

In terms of Robot library, a template could look like this:

```python
from robot.api import logger
from pyhive import hive

class HiveConnector(object):
    """
    Hive connector.    

    = Table of content =
    - Keywords    
    """

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self, host="", port="", username=""):
        self._conn = hive.Connection(host=host, port=port, username=username)

    # you add methods that will become keywords in Robot
```

Then in your keywords file(s) and/or test suites, you can import your newly created library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../Libraries/HiveConnector.py    ${DBHost}   ${DBPort}   ${DBUser}
```

You can find out more details in the documentation for Robot Framework: [Creating test libraries](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries).
This shouldn't even take that long and I'm sure Python has already modules for connecting to Hive/Impala/Spark. So you just need to wrap them in a custom library you create.